# How to add columns to output of EXEC statement in sql?

Tags: sql, exec

I have an sql statement

```
EXEC [dbo].[ABCD] @IsForecast='false', @Column='1', @Row='2',@NestType='', @Nesting='', 
@NestingBy='', @TimePeriodType='Month',@StartTime='Oct-2020', @EndTime='Oct-2020',@UserRole='5', @StudyId='1', 
@CategoryId='1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91',
        @DemographicId='Audience|3',
        @Filter='', 
        @MetricId='76|77|78|79|453|454|455|456|732|733|734|735|569|571|572', @Significance='None'
```

Now I want to add two more columns to the output of above statement with hard coded values, how do I do that?

Example if output of above EXEC statement is

```
     A      B
1  Team   Meeting
2  Hour   Glass
```

then I want to add two new columns to above output as

```
     A      B          NewCol1      NewCol2
1  Team   Meeting    ConstValue     ConstValue2
2  Hour   Glass      ConstValue     ConstValue2
```

And how do I apply where clauses to the output of above EXEC statement?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simpelest way would be to assign the output to a temp table and insert into it with the proc. Then simply select that temp table add any where conditions and join to any other table as normal.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ( A VARCHAR(MAX), B VARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @TempTable EXEC [dbo].[ABCD] ....(conditions go here)...

    SELECT A, B 'ConstValue' NewCol1, 'ConstValue' NewCol2 FROM  @TempTable
END
```